# mySQL - query to group values together

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query (below) which returns and ID value and two additional associated values (ReplacesReference). The query returns 2 records. I want to return one record so I need to concatenate the first "ReplacesReference" value with a comma ',' and the second "ReplacesReference" value.

my query is as follows

```
    select 
    distinct(c.wiid) as ID,    
    a.reference as ReplacesReference
    from npp_projects a, 
    npp_assoc b, 
    npp_projects c
    where a.id = b.parent_id     
    and b.type = 'replace' 
    and c.id = b.child_id
   and c.reference like '%EN 815%'
```

Its output is :

```
ID          |   ReplacesReference
====================================
CEN3406     |   I.S. EN 815:1996
CEN3406     |   I.S. EN 815:2004
```

I want to be able to return the below output:

```
ID                | ReplacesReference
====================================
CEN3406           |  I.S. EN 815:1996 , I.S. EN 815:2004
```

Many thanks in advance for your help - I am tearing my hair out with this one !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `group by` instead of `select distinct`.  Your use of parentheses around `c.wild` suggests that you don't understand how `select distinct` works.  It applies to all columns in the `select` list.  The parentheses don't affect it.  The query looks like:

```
select p2.wiid as ID,    
       group_concat(distinct p.reference separator ', ') as ReplacesReference
from npp_projects p join
     npp_assoc a
     on p.id = a.parent_id   
     npp_projects p2
     on p2.id = a.child_id
where a.type = 'replace' and p2.reference like '%EN 815%'
group by p2.wild;
```

The changes I made:

- Added the `group_concat()` to get the list you want.
- Added the `group by` to replace the `select distinct`.
- Changed the table aliases to use table abbreviations so the query is easier to follow.
- Changed the join syntax to the more powerful explicit `join` syntax.  As a simple rule:  just do not use commas in the `from` clause.

Comment: Thanks very much Gordon and also for the explanation of your code. Your code solution also works perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do something like:

SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(string SEPARATOR ' ') FROM table GROUP BY id;
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat